# Passing numbers to Grails taglibs

Tags: grails

My test case looks like:

```
   void testFormattedDiv() {
    String template = """<itld:formattedDiv numerator="1" denominator="1" format="###,###" nullNotifier="-"/>"""
    String output = applyTemplate(template)
    assertEquals "0", output
}
```

My taglib code starts off with:

```
    def formattedDiv = {attrs, body ->
    Number numerator = attrs.get('numerator') as Number
    Number denominator = attrs.get('denominator') as Number
```

However, I get a number format error.

```
Cannot cast object '1' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.lang.Number'
```

What is the correct way to pass the number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use braces (note that I've changed the template to a single-quoted rather than double-quoted string to stop Groovy interpreting the `${}` expressions too soon):

```
    String template = '''<itld:formattedDiv numerator="${1}" denominator="${1}" format="###,###" nullNotifier="-"/>'''
```

With GSP tag calls, if the entire content of a tag attribute is a `${}` expression then the value of the expression will be passed to the tag directly as its native type without being first converted to a string. But note this doesn't apply when there's other content in the attribute value as well as the `${}` expression, e.g. `ex="${ample}_1"` *would* be converted to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some code to parse the string into a valid number (within your taglib).

If you have a look at the source of the [FormatTagLib](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormatTagLib.groovy#L336) - you'll see that default grails tag libs also do such a handling.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat()
def numerator = attrs.get('numerator')

if (!(numerator instanceof Number)) {
    numerator = decimalFormat.parse(numerator as String)
}
```